# java reflection issue

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public static final <TypeVO extends BaseVo> List<SelectItem> populateSelectBoxForType(
            final Class<TypeVO> voClass, final String fieldName) {
        List<SelectItem> listSelectBox = null;
        final List<TypeVO> vosList = GenericEjbProxyFactory
                .getGenericTopValueObjectProxy(voClass)
                .getAllValueObjects(null);
        System.out.println("loaded vosList!!!!");
        if (vosList != null) {
            listSelectBox = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            for (final TypeVO currVo : vosList) {
                listSelectBox.add(new SelectItem(currVo.getInternalId(), currVo.getName()));
            }
        }
        return listSelectBox;
    }
```

As you see here, I'm using currVo.getName because always, currVo has a name property.

I want to be able to use also other fields from this currVo which has type as voClass, but not all currVo classes will contain this field so I have to use reflection to identify these getField method, something like:

```
for (final TypeVO currVo : vosList) {
                for (final Method m : voClass.getMethods()) {
                    if (m.getName().contains(fieldName)) {
                        listSelectBox.add(new SelectItem(
                                currVo.getInternalId(), currVo.m));
                    }
                }
            }
```

What I do not know is HOW I can use that specific method's value when I find it, exactly like currVo.getName (because, of course, **currVo.m is wrong**)?

Eg: If fieldName is "Age" I want to put in the list: `currVo.getAge()`... I am simply blocked here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m.invoke(currVo);
```

**See also:**

- [`Method` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)

Also note the correct way to look for a method as suggested by Nik and Bohemian.

Comment: `invoke` takes two arguments.

Comment: @Mat: It takes vararg as a second argument, which can be empty.

Comment: thanks for the new signature tip - didn't realise that reflection had gone varargs

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `invoke` method from the [`Method`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) class.

```
m.invoke(currVo, (Object[]) null);
```

(Assuming the method takes no parameter.)

This will work for JDK versions 1.4 and later, since they state:

> If the number of formal parameters required by the underlying method is 0, the supplied args array may be of length 0 **or null**

The one-parameter version of that call will not work on older JVMs.

Comment: This is the same as `m.invoke(currVo, new Object[] { null });` which may not be what you intended.

Comment: i also disagree - the null is a value and makes the Object[] length 1 - it should be length zero

Comment: You are right. null is "cast" to `Object[]` not as an array of length 0 or 1.

Comment: I was a bit off though, the explicit cast to `Object[]` is necessary for it to compile without warnings on 1.6 at least.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand it correctly that you want to invoke the method `m` on your object `currVo`?  Then it's simply

```
m.invoke(currVo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection to get the getFieldName method and invoke it, as follows:

```
 Method method = voClass.getMethod("get" + fieldName); // the getter with no params in the signature
 Object value = method.invoke(currVo}); // invoke with no params
 listSelectBox.add(new SelectItem(currVo.getInternalId(), value));
```

Note: This assumes that fieldName is leading uppercase, eg "Value", not "value", so prepending it with "get" gives the exact method name, eg "getValue"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i got ur question right, but what i feel  u are asking wud be answered by following code:

```
// Class is whatever is the type u r using
Method mthd = Class.getMethod("get" + fieldName); //in case method don't have any parameters.
listSelectBox.add(mthd.invoke(currVo));
```

otherwise ignore.